# How to convert date timezone to utc using momentjs in Angular 6

Tags: angular, momentjs, datetime-format

I'm having issue to convert date with timezone to utc format.

How to convert `2019-06-13T00:00:00+08:00` to this format `2019-06-12T16:00:00.000Z`

**app.ts**

```
orders() {
  this.orderService
    .orders(
      this.selectedType.value,
      moment(this.startDate).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z'),
      moment(this.endDate).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z'),
    )
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.allSub))
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.loading.stop();
      },
      err => {
        serviceHttpErrorHandler(err);
      },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`moment(this.startDate).utc().format()`

Hope it helps!

Comment: it does convert like this `2019-06-12T16:00:00Z` but api expecting like `2019-06-12T16:00:00.000Z`. Any idea?

Comment: With moment.js: 'moment(this.startDate).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");'
With Date: new Date(this.startDate).toISOString()

Comment: Issue fixed with `moment(this.startDate).toISOString()`. thanks @lorengo